# How can I pass data from node js to html?

Tags: html, node.js

How to pass data from node.js to html page? I know that there are templating engines, but they are used with express - I need it in native nodejs. Tried to do it like this:

```js
let str = ''
Post.find({}, function(err, docs) { 
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    
    for (let i in docs) {
        str += '<tr><td>' + docs[i].title + '</td><td>' + docs[i].text + '</td></tr>'
    }
});
```

But how do I pass this variable `str` to the right place in the html file? To have something like this:

```html
<div class="posts">
    <table>
        str
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create unique string, say `#str#`, read the file then replace that string

```
let str = ''
Post.find({}, function(err, docs) { 
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    for (let i in docs) {
        str += '<tr><td>' + docs[i].title + '</td><td>' + docs[i].text + '</td></tr>'
    }
    
    /*
    <div class="posts">
        <table>
          #str#
        </table>
    </div>
    */
    let template = fs.readFileSync('template.html');
    template = template.replace('#str#', str);
});
```

or use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) html parser

```
// template.html without "str"
/*
<div class="posts">
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
*/

let template = fs.readFileSync('template.html');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(template);
$('.posts table').html(str);
```